# I am trying to create a table with 2 foreign keys but keep getting an error of missing left parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table downloads (
Download_id      varchar2(150)          not null,
User_id          varchar2(150)          references users (User_id), foreign key,
Download_date    date                   not null,
File_name        varchar(300)           not null,
Product_id       varchar(300)           references Products (Product_id), foreign key,

constraint users_user_id foreign key(User_id) references users(User_id),
constraint prod_product_id foreign key(Product_id) references products(Product_id)
);
```

Comment: Don't try to define each fk twice. Keep the latter ones.

Comment: Id's as varchar 150/300? I'd consider int instead.

Comment: I still get missing left parenthesis error cod

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `FOREIGN KEY` key words when you are using in-line constraints and you don't need both out-of-line and in-line constraints:

```sql
create table downloads (
Download_id      varchar2(150) not null,
User_id          varchar2(150) references users (User_id),
Download_date    date          not null,
File_name        varchar(300)  not null,
Product_id       varchar(300)  references Products (Product_id)
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=494756ce5bc18817242d53dc35bf230f)

Also, you should consider:

- naming your constraints;
- using integers as the primary key rather than (large) strings;
- not prefixing the column identifiers with the table name; and
- using `IDENTITIY` columns (if you're on Oracle 12 or later, otherwise use sequences).

Like this:

```sql
create table downloads (
  id         NUMBER(10,0)
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
             CONSTRAINT downloads__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  User_id    NUMBER(10,0)
             CONSTRAINT downloads__user_id__fk REFERENCES users (id),
  datetime   DATE
             CONSTRAINT downloads__datetime__nn NOT NULL,
  File_name  VARCHAR2(300)
             CONSTRAINT downloads__file_name__nn NOT NULL,
  Product_id NUMBER(10,0)
             CONSTRAINT downloads__product_id__FK REFERENCES Products (id)
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1b71e3f8c91d5afc7b03cd2c6978a824)

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type
02267. 00000 -  "column type incompatible with referenced column type"
*Cause:    The datatype of the referencing column is incompatible with the

Comment: @BrendaRushe If you are trying to use the bottom statement then you need to note that I have changed the data type of all the `id` columns to numbers (including in the `users` and `products` tables) and removed the table name prefixes in the column identifiers; if you don't want this then you should use your previous column names / data types (but please don't do that as 300 bytes per primary key value is far too much and you should get into better practices).

Comment: ok thank you. I'm just beginning to learn SQL and I greatly appreciate your help!